# Released apk is showing Objectmapper exception "disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS" for firebase database object sending

Tags: android, serialization, firebase-realtime-database, fasterxml, objectmapper

> I am trying to implement firebase database to send class object to database. In debug mode, it works fine but in Signed apk , it shows the following error. Parsing data from database is okey.
>
> Stack Trace:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.xxxx.razon30.movietest, PID: 15017
                                               java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No serializer found for class com.xxxx.razon30.movietest.af and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) )
                                                   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.convertValue(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.example.razon30.movietest.fr.onClick(Unknown Source)
                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class com.example.razon30.movietest.af and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) )
                                                   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.convertValue(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at com.example.razon30.movietest.fr.onClick(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204) 
                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

> My actual code was:

```
 ClassReview classReview = new ClassReview(u_name, u_review, u_rat);
 myFirebaseRef.child(m_id).push().setValue(map);
```

> I have searched for solution then i got this and applied

```
 ClassReview classReview = new ClassReview(u_name, u_review, u_rat);
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 Map<String, Object> map = mapper.convertValue(classReview, Map.class);
 myFirebaseRef.child(m_id).push().setValue(map);
```

> But the problem remains same. This is my pro-guard rules for firebase

```
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class com.firebase.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.firebase.quickstart.database.viewholder.** {
*;
 }

-keepclassmembers class com.google.firebase.quickstart.database.models.**   {*;}
-keep  class com.fasterxml.** { *; }
-keep  class com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.** {*;}
-keep  class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.** {*;}
```